# selecting specific text node with xpath?

Tags: xpath

```
<html>
apple
<Br>
orange
<br>
drugs
</html>
```

can you do something like

```
//html/text()[2]
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
apple
<br/>
orange
<br/>
drugs
</html>
```

> ```
> //html/text()[2]
> ```

returns `orange` for me @ http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx. What language are you dealing with?

Comment: `doesn't work` is vague. are you getting any errors? come on.. more information *please*